# StackOverflowException caused on DefaultCamelContext.start(), appears to be caused by camel goint into an infinite loop

Tags: apache-camel, stack-overflow

I have searched this and haven't found a question for this already.  I am creating a camel route which watches a folder for shapefiles (.shp).  The code below is the code implementing the camel route.

```
final String filePath = settings.getSetting(GMTI_VOCAB.SHAPEFILE_PATH);
logger.debug("filePath={}", filePath);
final File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.mkdir())
{
  logger.warn("Shapefile path did not exist. Creating directory.");
}

logger.debug("Creating file route.");
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder()
{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        String path = String.format("file://%s?noop=true&include=.*shp$", file.getAbsolutePath());
        logger.debug("Route is: {}", path);
        from(path).bean(this, "process(${file:path})");
    }
 });
 logger.debug("Starting context");
 context.start();
 logger.info("Communicator started!");
```

Currently the the filePath returned is just "shapefile" resulting in file.getAbsolutePath() returning "C:\Users\medderssc\gmti_intestor\shapefiles".  Resulting path returned is

```
from("file://C:\Users\medderssc\gmti_intestor\shapefiles?noop=true&include=.*shp$").bean(this, "process(${file:path})");
```

context is a DefaultCamelContext and camel is being imported via maven with the following entry in the POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

"Communicator started" is never output, the program crashes prior to that, telling me the error is occurring during context.start().  The stack trace below shows a StackOverflowException.  Note the stack itself repeats several times, implying that camel itself is somehow going into some kind of infinitely recursive loop.  There is no further camel configuration beyond what is in the posted code.  Can anyone help?  Exception stack below:

> Oct 1, 2012 9:33:50 AM com.saic.ogc.client.BaseClient createMessageFactory
>   INFO: Defaulting to built-in message factory...
>   Oct 1, 2012 9:33:50 AM com.saic.ogc.client.BaseClient initTemplate
>   INFO: Setting interceptor!
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> > ```
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.toString(RouteDefinition.java:119)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.toString(RoutesDefinition.java:60)
> > at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.toString(RouteBuilder.java:58)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.description(BeanDefinition.java:81)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.toString(BeanDefinition.java:70)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.toString(RouteDefinition.java:119)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.toString(RoutesDefinition.java:60)
> > at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.toString(RouteBuilder.java:58)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.description(BeanDefinition.java:81)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.toString(BeanDefinition.java:70)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.toString(RouteDefinition.java:119)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.toString(RoutesDefinition.java:60)
> > at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.toString(RouteBuilder.java:58)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.description(BeanDefinition.java:81)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.toString(BeanDefinition.java:70)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.toString(RouteDefinition.java:119)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.RoutesDefinition.toString(RoutesDefinition.java:60)
> > at org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder.toString(RouteBuilder.java:58)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.description(BeanDefinition.java:81)
> > at org.apache.camel.model.BeanDefinition.toString(BeanDefinition.java:70)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
> > at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
> > at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> > ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at first glance, the issue appears to be that your `.bean(this,...)` is referring to an anonymous class (`new RouteBuilder()`) and will try to run the `configure()` (hence the recursion/sfo)...try using a separate class for your bean/process() method...

Comment: Rookie mistake. Forgot to watch my scope.  Meant for "this" to refer to the object starting the route.  Thanks for bringing my attention to that.  Created a separate reference to the intended object and passed that into the .bean(), works now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a RouteBuilder which implemented Processor (because I was being lazy). Turns out that this caused infinite recursion. The fix was to move the implementation of process(...) to it's own class.